# SUSPICIOUS TOKEN IN PHANTOM WALLET

Tags: token

I have a random token in my wallet that i do not recognize and would like to know how to remove or if its safe or not. Please can someone advise. Its not on the NFT tabh but on the token tab. I am worried about clicking anything without guidance.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about Solana development

Answer (score 1):

You can burn it... Im not affiliated but you can try https://sol-incinerator.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help. That worked perfectly.